# PHP preg_replace first space char from a tag

Tags: php, regex

I have this link html code:
`<a href="/drupal-7.41/en/node/3" title="">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a>`
I need to replace the first space between the a tag with a `<br />`

So the result should look like: `<a href="/drupal-7.41/en/node/3" title="">Lorem<br />Ipsum Dolor</a>`

I tried something like `(?:<.*">.*)(\s)` but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
(<a[^>]*>)(.+?)(\s)(.+)(<\/a>)
```

And replace it by:

```
$1$2<br />$4$5
```

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/sI4cI9/2

Comment: @calculataur Consider in accepting it if it really helps. Also let me do a little edit. Since you want just the `a` tag